# Is it an anti-pattern to use the suffix "Template" for the class name of the template method pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, naming-conventions, anti-patterns

I am using the template method pattern.

My abstract class has a skeleton method processing iteration and logging.

like this:

```
abstract public class ImportingTemplate implements Importing{
    
    
    public void importArticles(List<Long> articleIds)
    {
        for(long articleId : articleIds)
        {
            Log log = importArticle(articleId);
            logService.save(log);
        }
    }
    
    protected abstract Log importArticle(long articleId);

}
```

I can't use "Importing" because it is a name for the interface.

I can't come up with a better name than using "Template" on the suffix.

Is it an anti-pattern to use the suffix "Template" for the class name of the "template method pattern"?

Is it better to use "ImportingContext"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One sensible convention is to use an *agent noun* for interfaces (and function types). In your case the name of the interface would then be *Importer*. However, you may not be able to change the name of the interface.

If a subclass of your abstract class is not meant to have a state (instance variables) I would use a *mass noun* like for instance *ArticleImport*. After all, the class handles articles so it makes sense to use the word *Article* in the name.

Comment: If I use `Importer` as interface name (has a signiture : _public void importArticles(List<Long> articleIds)_)and use `TwitterImport` and `FacebookImport` as subclass's name,  
What is a good name for an abstract skeletal class? I want to encapsulate the loop and logging by using Template-Method-Pattern.  
Would it be better to name it `ArticleImportTemplate` to indicate that I used Template-Method-Pattern?
or `MediaImport` is better?

Comment: @kang *MediaImport* seems like a good name if it's any kind of media that can be imported (text, images, etc.). I would not use *Template* in the name because that information can already be extracted from the keyword *abstract* (any abstract class is a kind of template).